# java timestamps calculate overlap duration with interval

Tags: java, time, intervals, overlap, duration

I have many timestamps (`start, end`) which define an interval and want to efficiently check if they overlap another single interval. If yes, compute overlap duration, otherwise return 0.

interval: `18:00` same day until `08:00` the next day.

```
start                  | end
2018-01-02 14:59:18.922|2018-01-02 14:59:38.804
2018-01-02 18:32:59.348|2018-01-02 20:30:41.192
2018-01-02 01:54:59.363|2018-01-02 01:54:59.363
2018-01-03 00:10:38.831|2018-01-03 00:11:53.103
```

I am unsure how to efficiently define *the next day* efficiently.

## edit

```
LocalDate
```

has a method `toInterval().overlaps(anotherInterval)`. I simply am unsure how to get fitting interval (18:00 - 08:00 next day) in a **generic** way, i.e. without manually reading the `YYYMMDD` and then creating a new object.

- a bit similar is [Find if hours ranges overlap regardless of the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810914/find-if-hours-ranges-overlap-regardless-of-the-date/38817479#38817479)

### edit 2

`toInterval` is only present for jodatime - not `java.time` / JSR-310. What would be a viable way to calculate overlap duration with java.time?

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap]

### edit3

A solution with jodaTime:

```
val begin = new DateTime(new java.sql.Timestamp().getTime())
val stop = new DateTime(new java.sql.Timestamp().getTime())
val i1 = new Interval(begin, stop)

val start = new DateTime(begin.year.get   , begin.monthOfYear.get, begin.dayOfMonth.get, startHour, 0, 0, 0);
val endIntermediate =stop.toDateTime.plusDays(1)
val end = new DateTime(endIntermediate.year.get   , endIntermediate.monthOfYear.get, endIntermediate.dayOfMonth.get, endHour, 0, 0, 0);
val i2 = new Interval(start, end)

val overlap = i1.overlap(i2)
val overlapDurationOrNull = overlap.toDuration
```

seems to work, but still is clumsy.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Is `interval: 18:00 same day until 08:00 the next day` the input "interval" to be checked against all periods in the table for overlaps?

Comment: Fore each entry in the samples above I want to check a single interval (18:00-08:00). and if there is any overlap, compute overlap duration.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap(org.joda.time.ReadableInterval), http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#toDuration()

Comment: *how to get fitting interval (18:00 - 08:00 next day) in a generic way* what does that mean, precisely? What is your input, and what is your expected output? Same day as what? Next day of what?

Comment: I mean that I do not want to extract `yyMMdd` (i.e. the day) from start end end interval) and then manually instantiate a new object which has a fitting date and 18:00 and a second object with the next date and 08:00, but define 18:00-08:00 in a way that they are valid for any input day.

Comment: How else could you possibly do? You have a start date, and you want to find the next day of that date, but without extracting the day of the start date? Where would you find it then?

Comment: So there is no such notion of a relative/generic interval? I.e starting 18:00 today until 08:00 the next day?

Comment: Yes, there is. You do that by taking the same day as the original date, and change the hour.

Comment: With `there is`, you mean I would manually need to emulate it, i.e. extracting the fitting date from start and then begin the calculation? There is no notion of `generics /relative` interval by a java time library?

Comment: You can just check if the end of an event is after the start of the next event.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to write code to implement what you want. Joda-time doesn't have a magic method doing exactly what you want. But it has all the building blocks to make it easy to implement.

Comment: [The `Interval` class in in the ThreeTen Extra library](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html). Not sure exactly how much it helps, nor whether that library is still being maintained.

Comment: Thanks for all the edits, but I am sorry, it is still very unclear. From 18:00 *on which day* to 08:00 the next? I also find it confusing that I don’t see the times 18 and 8 in your Joda-Time solution code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the following method gives you the equivalent of your Joda-Time solution.

```
private static final LocalTime START = LocalTime.of(18, 0);
private static final LocalTime END = LocalTime.of(8, 0);

public static Duration overlap(ZonedDateTime currentStart, ZonedDateTime currentEnd) {
    ZonedDateTime singleIntervalStart = currentStart.with(START);
    ZonedDateTime singleIntervalEnd = currentStart.plusDays(1).with(END);
    if (currentEnd.isBefore(singleIntervalStart)) {
        // no overlap
        return Duration.ZERO;
    }
    ZonedDateTime overlapStart = currentStart.isBefore(singleIntervalStart)
            ? singleIntervalStart : currentStart;
    ZonedDateTime overlapEnd = currentEnd.isBefore(singleIntervalEnd)
            ? currentEnd : singleIntervalEnd;
    return Duration.between(overlapStart, overlapEnd);
}
```

For trying it out with the timestamps from your question I am using the following utility method:

```
private static void demo(String from, String to) {
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Atlantic/Stanley");
    Duration overlapDuration = overlap(LocalDateTime.parse(from).atZone(zone),
            LocalDateTime.parse(to).atZone(zone));
    System.out.println("" + from + " - " + to + ": " + overlapDuration);
}
```

Now I call it like this:

```
    demo("2018-01-02T14:59:18.922", "2018-01-02T14:59:38.804");
    demo("2018-01-02T18:32:59.348", "2018-01-02T20:30:41.192");
    demo("2018-01-02T01:54:59.363", "2018-01-02T01:54:59.363");
    demo("2018-01-03T00:10:38.831", "2018-01-03T00:11:53.103");
```

And the output is:

```
2018-01-02T14:59:18.922 - 2018-01-02T14:59:38.804: PT0S
2018-01-02T18:32:59.348 - 2018-01-02T20:30:41.192: PT1H57M41.844S
2018-01-02T01:54:59.363 - 2018-01-02T01:54:59.363: PT0S
2018-01-03T00:10:38.831 - 2018-01-03T00:11:53.103: PT0S
```

In the first example 14:59 is before 18:00, so the result is an overlap of 0. In the second example the whole interval is counted as overlap (nearly 2 hours). Note that in the last two examples no overlap is reported because the the times are many hours before 18:00. I am unsure whether this is what you wanted since the times are also before 08:00.

Comment: looks really great. That is what I wanted (0).

Comment: I think adding " || singleIntervalEnd.isBefore(currentStart)" would be better. Otherwise, nagative value might be returned.

Comment: @ShengfengLi In this case, since `SingleIntervalEnd` is on the next day compared to `currentStart` (it has been initialized that way), it cannot be before. So your addition is not necessary (also does no harm). Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `LocalDate.plusDays` to add a day.

Assuming an iteration where the following are to be compared:

```
LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-02T14:59:18"),
              d2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-02T14:59:38");
```

You can create the `18:00` and `08:00` date/time objects using:

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(d1.toLocalDate(), LocalTime.of(18, 0));
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(d1.toLocalDate().plusDays(1), 
                                       LocalTime.of(8, 0));
```

I've assumed that `18:00` is on the same day as `d1`.

Comment: But jodatime `Interval` which would offer `overlap` is not supported in JDK8-java-time API.